# Getting Image URLs in a Web Directory

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to get URLs of all images or lets say "JPEG" files in a web directory (www.abcde.com/images). I just want their URLs in an array.. I couldnt manage that. Could u pls help me with this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need to give us some more information. Do you have access to the index file, listing via plain html the files as a "<a href=" link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have access to an index file you could simply load via NSURL the whole html file and cut out the link lines. This however will not work (or hardly work) when you want to search ("spider or crawl") for links in more complex documents. On iOS i would suggest you use the simple, yet quite powerfull "hpple" framework (https://github.com/topfunky/hpple). It is used to parse html. You can search with it for certain html elements, such as `<a href...>` constructs.

a sample with hpple could looks like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatver.com/images"];
NSData *data = [NSData url];
TFHpple *hppleParser = [TFHpple data];
NSString *images = @"//img"; // grabbs all image tags
NSArray *node = [hppleParser searchWithXPathQuery:images]
```

find a bigger example at http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

Create a server side script(eg php) which gives you a list of all images in that directory as xml or json. From iOS send a request to that script get the xml or JSON parse it and use the image urls.

Comment: Is this the only way? Any internal way?