# How can parse all the images form Website in IOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, parsing, uiwebview, uiimage

I like to implement image upload functionality in my app.For that I like to give some option for user to choose image.

One of the option is choose image from website.

If the user enter an url link in the text box and click the get images button means. I like to display all the images in that particular link

But I am not having any idea about this.

I have explain my requirement below

**1)Enter the url in a text box**

**2)Click the get images button**

**3)Parse all the images from that particular url**

**4)Display all the images in the Imageview**

And also to illustrate my requirement I have attached the screenshot below

[image]

[image]

If anybody work around this functionality means please suggest me some idea

Thanks

Comment: in your url contains images or images url ?

Comment: its contain images like http://www.imore.com/iphone-6. From this like I like to parse images

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourwebvsite.com/image.png"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
    UIImageView *displayImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [displayImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
    [displayImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [self.view addSubview:displayImageView];
}
```

Or if you want all the images from a web directory. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14338527/2053537) and save all the images in an array then display the images in a `UIImageView` like my code above.

Comment: Please refer the above image